# Syntax for creating conditional queries based on other variables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a problem with using `::` and `->` operators for models

Let's assume I want to make some simple search. I can do it this way:

```
$model = SomeModel::where('id', '>', 2)->where('id', '<', 10)->get();
```

After model name I need to use `::` operator and then standard `->` operator.

But now assume we have `$minId` and `$maxId` in some variables and if those variables values are empty we don't want to use where conditions:

```
$minId = '';

$maxId = '';

$model = SomeModel::where('id','>','0'); // dummy where here

if ($minId != '') {
  $model = $model->where('id','>',$minId);
}
if ($maxId != '') {
  $model = $model->where('id','<',$maxId);
}
$model = $model->get();
```

The problem is how to use `::` before conditions. You cannot use `$model = SomeModel::` so I've added dummy where `where('id','>','0')` that is always true. Now in conditional `where` I can use `->` operator without a problem.

Can it be done some other way without using extra condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the query first (this is what eloquent will do anyway):

```
$query = Model::query();

if (..) { $query->where(..) }
if (..) { $query->where(..) }

$query->get();
```

And for something like this you can use scopes, for example:

```
// Model
public function scopeMinId($q, $id)
{
  if ( ! empty($id)) $q->where('id', '>=', $id);
}
```

Then you can easily use (no matter what `minId` and `maxId` is set to):

```
Model::minId($minId)->maxId($maxId)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. `query()` is what I needed here